# Introductory text on Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, hopf-algebras

Is there an introductory (but as complete as possible) text on Hopf algebras like Abe or Sweedler but working when possible over arbitrary commutative rings instead fields? "Like Abe or Sweedler" means that I prefer to avoid texts focused in cohomology applications, usually working in the graded setting, etc. (Milnor-Moore, May-Ponto).

Also, I don't mind if it deals only or mainly with commutative Hopf algebras.

Comment: What sort of questions would you like the text to deal with? A commutative Hopf algebra, for example, is just an algebraic group (at least if you put some finiteness conditions on it). So from that point of view, you will have texts dealing with one set of questions. But there are other options too.

Comment: There is a list of references at the very beginning of §1 of [Victor Reiner's and my *Hopf algebras in combinatorics*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf) (which itself might be a useful text to you, if you care about the (non-super) graded Hopf algebras that come up in combinatorics). It separately mentions three references that work over commutative rings. In my personal experience, there is just not enough literature on Hopf algebras over rings -- so when I need something about them, I look it up over a field and try to adapt the proof to the ring case.

Comment: Thank you very much. This monograph will be very helpful to me.